# Terminal leaving a blank line on High Sierra when tabs are used

Tags: terminal, bash, high-sierra

Since the upgrade from El Capitain to High Sierra (I jumped over Sierra), my terminal leaves a blank line at the very bottom as soon as I open another tab. See picture as example:

[image: Mac Terminal]

Here is my ~/.bash_profile

```
# Beautify bash prompt
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/on \1/'
}
export PS1="\e[1;30m\u\e[m in \e[0;34m\w\e[m \e[0;32m\$(parse_git_branch)\e[m \e[0;37m// \$(date '+%H:%M')\e[m\n$ "

# Extend PATH for Homebrew
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php70)/bin:$PATH"

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

It is not a big issue, but somewhat annoying especially when working with tmux during ssh sessions.

Does anyone know what is causing this or how I might resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this, at least temporarily, by opening the Inspector via Shell -> Show Inspector, going to the info tab, and reducing the "columns" by 1.  Then I dragged the window back to the desired size and it seems to look proper now.  I had to do that for each tab.  It seems to need to be done again every time I restart terminal, which is monumentally annoying, but fortunately I don't close it all that often.  It seems to work, at least as a kludgy workaround.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This actually worked. I will accept this answer until something better shows up.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked.  It did seem to persist through a reboot for a patch, so as long as you don't manually quit terminal, you may be able to avoid having to do it again.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been corrected in macOS Mojave 10.14.

Comment: A some helpful advice:  it's always good to supplement your answer with references; either externally sourced or some info that you were able to "validate" the fix through your own experience.  +1 to get you off to a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It was just from my own experience.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not the ideal solution, but try adding

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to set number of rows of window 1 to 100'
```

to your `~/.bash_profile`.
This runs an AppleScript every time you open a new tab. (This may not work for you specifically. I don't know enough about how tmux works)